# How to find the highest COUNT in GROUP BY query? - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join, select, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I need to find the name, street, city, state, and country of the airline with the maximum total number of flights.

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT MAX(tName) as name, MAX(tStreet) as street, MAX(tCity) as city, MAX(tState) as state, 
MAX(tCountry) as country, MAX(totalFlights) as maxTotal
FROM(
SELECT FLIGHT.name as tName, AIRLINE.street as tStreet, AIRLINE.city as tCity, AIRLINE.state as 
tState, AIRLINE.country as tCountry, COUNT(flightNumber) as totalFlights
FROM FLIGHT
LEFT JOIN AIRLINE ON AIRLINE.name = FLIGHT.name
GROUP BY FLIGHT.name)as t;
```

Here are the two tables I am joining together:

```
CREATE TABLE AIRLINE (
name        VARCHAR(30),            /* Airline name */
street      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Airline headquater location - street */
city        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Airline headquater location - city */
state       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   /* Airline headquater location - state */
postcode    CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,   /* Airline headquater location - postcode */
country     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Airline headquater location - country */
phone       VARCHAR(20),            /* phone number */
website     VARCHAR(60),            /* Manager start date */
ceo         VARCHAR(30),            /* CEO of the airline */
CONSTRAINT AIRLINE_PK PRIMARY KEY(name),
CONSTRAINT AIRLINE_CK1 UNIQUE(phone),
CONSTRAINT AIRLINE_CK2 UNIQUE(website));

CREATE TABLE FLIGHT (
name            VARCHAR(30),            /* airline name */
flightNumber    CHAR(6),                /* Flight number */
departAirport   VARCHAR(50),            /* Departure airport */
departTime      DATETIME    NOT NULL,   /* Departure date and time */
arriveAirport   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,   /* Arriving airport */
arriveTime      DATETIME,               /* Arriving date and time */
capacity        DECIMAL(3)  NOT NULL,   /* Capacity for passengers */
airliner        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   /* Aircraft for passengers */
CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_PK PRIMARY KEY(flightNumber, departAirport, departTime),
CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_CK1 UNIQUE (flightNumber, arriveAirport, arriveTime),
CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES AIRLINE(name));
```

Here is the link to the db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbCqw2UDM2gGZDPnMbyA6k/0

The results I receive are:

```
 name:              street:                       city:    state: country:  maxTotal:
'Virgin Australia', 'B-12 Jianguomenwai Avenue', 'Mascot', 'VIC', 'China', '12'
```

I need to receive this output:

```
 name:    street:           city:     state:  country:    maxTotal:
'Qantas', '10 Bourke Road', 'Mascot', 'NSW', 'Australia', '12'
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's just a row-limiting query:

```
select 
    a.*,
    (select count(*) from flight f where f.name = a.name) no_flights
from arline a
order by no_flights desc
limit 1
```

On the other hand, if you want to allow top ties, you can use `rank()` (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
select *
from 
    select t.*, rank() over(order by no_flights desc) rn
    from (
        select 
            a.*,
            (select count(*) from flight f where f.name = a.name) no_flights
        from arline a
        order by no_flights desc
    ) t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: @Noods: I had a `on` where it should be `where`. Fixed.